# finding specific element which exists in multiple places but has same id,class

Tags: ruby, watir, pageobjects

How to find an element  if it exists in multiple places in a page but has same id under same class?
For example:
There are two text fields with the same id and I would like to choose the 2nd one.
It works when I just write the watir/ruby(without using page object)
@b.text_fields(:id => 'color').last.set "red"

But I am unsuccessful so far to make it work using page object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should never have two html elements with the same id.

Comment: Somehow the web developer has used the same id. what if one of the element is hidden?

Comment: Having two elements on the same page with the same id is broken code.  It doesn't matter what type the elements are, **any** two elements with the same id on the same page is wrong.  It's a bug, and it needs to be fixed, just like any other bug.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the best solution is to update the fields to have unique ids.

However, assuming that is not possible, you can solve the problem using an `:index` locator. The following page object finds the 2nd color field, which is equivalent to Watir's `@b.text_field(:id => 'color', :index => 1).set`:

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  text_field(:color_1, id: 'color', index: 0)
  text_field(:color_2, id: 'color', index: 1)
end
```

Which would be called like:

```
page = MyPage.new(browser)
page.color_1 = 'red'
page.color_2 = 'blue'
```

If you are actually trying to the last field, ie replicate `@b.text_fields(:id => 'color').last.set`, then the `:index` would be "-1":

```
text_field(:color_2, id: 'color', index: -1)
```

Note that similar can be done when locating the fields dynamically within a method (as opposed to defined by an accessor):

```
class MyPage
  include PageObject

  def set_colors(color_1, color_2)
    text_field_element(id: 'color', index: 0).value = color_1
    text_field_element(id: 'color', index: 1).value = color_2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@b.text_fields(:id=>'color',:index=>1).set "red"
```

This can solve your problem.

Comment: I believe the question is looking for a page-object gem solution as opposed to a pure Watir solution.